# Nginx access_log default flush time

Tags: nginx

How frequently nginx flushes its buffer to access_log by default ?

In manual there is not info, just setup syntax:

```
access_log path [format [buffer=size [flush=time]] [if=condition]];
```

Comment: By default nginx does not use buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nginx doesn't flush unless you specify the `flush` option (even if you have specified the `buffer` option).

Here's an example of how to buffer packets of 8k to the log every five minutes:

```
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main buffer=8k flush=5m;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error, nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "main" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:42

Answer (score 2):

Did a bit of research on this myself, and as far as I can tell nginx doesn't flush buffers at all if you do not specify the flush parameter. (Or if it does, it's more than 20 minutes.)

The only exception is if you restart the server, the logs are flushed before restart.

So if you specify the buffer you should make sure to specify the flush time too.

Comment: Are you talking about disk syncing, or buffer flushing? After all, you see each HTTP request as a line if you `tail` the log.

Answer (score 0):

From the nginx documentation [1]:

```
When buffering is enabled, the data will be written to the file:

-  if the next log line does not fit into the buffer;
-  if the buffered data is older than specified by the flush parameter (1.3.10, 1.2.7);
-  when a worker process is re-opening log files or is shutting down.
```

Of course if you do not specify the `flush` parameter the second condition can not become true.

[1] http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log